# Ajax loader gif showing every time Sencha 2 app does a Ajax request

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Whats the smartest way to add a ajax loader gif image in the center of screen every time my Sencha 2 app does a ajax request? Should be some kind of code snippet which should check if a internal Javascript counter which keeps track of all open Ajax requests is > than 0 and thereby show the loader gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I just put the code below before a ajax request.

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    masked: {
        xtype: 'loadmask',
        message: 'A message..',
        indicator: false
    }
});
```

You might want to extend the ajax class and add it there to get this to work for every ajax request.

Comment: thanks for your help, I added a listener to the Ext.Ajax singleton and that fixed it.